# What is the difference between 設問 and 質問?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

The two words appear to both mean the English word `question`. Are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a native speaker, but as I understand it: 質問 means a question in general; 設問 is a question that has been *posed.* That is, 設問する is to ask a question that you already know the answer to or for the purpose of generating discussion.

Be careful, however, because what we call a "question" on an exam in English is a 問題 in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

According to the dictionary:

せつもん【設問】: a question to assess the knowledge of a candidate or student.
問題を作って出すこと。また、その問題。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/124833/meaning/m0u/設問/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/124833/meaning/m0u/%E8%A8%AD%E5%95%8F/)

しつもん【質問】: a question about something you don't know.
わからないところや疑わしい点について問いただすこと。また、その内容。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/98804/meaning/m1u/質問/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/98804/meaning/m1u/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F/)

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Was it because setumon might be extended beyond just students/candidates?